# Add logo / text in to the Ubuntu encryption phrase

Tags: boot, logo, decryption

We will add an logo or an text to the boot screen because if someone finds a lost laptop from our company, he has the chance to get in contact with us. We need the encryption so it's not possible to change the plymouth booting logo, so we think that the logo in the passphrase for decryption can be changed or some text can be added.

[image]

Comment: My guess is you're asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, but it's best if we're not guessing & told what OS/release you're asking about.

Comment: @user535733 but the problem is that the logo just will load after the decryption.